# Don't show him what are in the box!

Tags: grammatical-number, questions

Two guys meet each other at night and one of them shows the other a box where there are three guns. Then a police officer appears and asks:

*What **is** in the box?*

Can the guy whom was shown the box whisper to his pal

*Don't show him what **are** in the box!* ?

I read that if we knew or presupposed about something that was plural we could say sentences like that with plural forms or verbs. This way the police officer doesn't know anything about the singular/plural form of what is in the box. Therefore he uses **"is"**. However, the boys knowing the amount of the guns is three use **"are"**. Am I right?

P.S. If he can, will it be wrong if he still says:

*Don't show him what **is** in the box!* ?

Comment: 'Don't show him what is in the box' is the more natural and is equivalent to 'Don't show him the contents of the box'.

Comment: But the "are" version is not incorrect?

Comment: I would take it as an indication of "illiterate" speech.

Comment: Not ungrammatical, but at best highfalutin'. I'd avoid it.

Comment: The word you're using is "what", and it is singular. I would not use "are".

Answer (score 1):

The entire embedded question

> *what [is/are] in the box*

is a noun clause serving as direct object for the main clause’s verb *show*.

This embedded clause has its own subject, which here happens to be *what*; when it’s the subject of a finite clause as it is here, *what* by itself is always singular and so demands a singular verb. Correct agreement therefore demands *is* here, never *are*.

Try it with other embedded question clauses. Consider questions like:

- **Who** is on the phone?
- **What** is next?
- **Which** is best?

Now imagine that the *X* here is that same embedded question just given:

- I’ll show you **X**.
- I don’t know **X**.
- I wonder **X**.

That yields things like:

- I’ll show you **who is** on the phone.
- I don’t know **what is** next.
- I wonder **which is** best.

When the qustion word is not itself the subject, you have to look
at the actual subject’s grammatical number to pick its verb:

- What are **your friends** doing?
- Which **ideas** are discarded?
- What **noises** are you afraid of?
- How is **she** feeling?
- How are **you** feeling?
- **Whose parents** are missing?
- When is **she** calling?
- When are **they** calling?
- Why is **she** calling?
- Why are **they** calling?

Now embed those, taking care to undo any inversion where needed:

- I’ll show you what **your friends *are*** doing.
- I don’t know **which ideas *are*** discarded.
- I wonder what noises **you *are*** afraid of.
- I’m not sure how **she *is*** feeling.
- I’ll ask how **you *are*** feeling.
- I can see **whose parents *are*** missing.
- I always know when **she *is*** calling.
- I can tell you when **they *are*** calling.
- Let me show you why she is calling.
- I wonder why they are calling.

Sometimes you can get an implied plural subject when the interrogative
is acting as the determiner of an implied subject that’s been omitted 
because it was just used.

- Whose **marbles are** in the box?
  I wonder **whose are** there.
- Which **ideas are** best? 
  I don’t know **which are** best.

But with *what*, you can’t leave out the noun or pronoun.

- What new **products are** ready?
  I can’t tell you **what *ones* are** ready.

Comment: Can "who" act as the determiner? If there were something alive in the box in my sentence, for example, three little dwarves, would it be correct to say "Don't show him who are in the box"?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko No, it can't. You can say "I know the people who are coming" but you cannot say "I don't know who are coming".

Comment: Even if I know beforehand there are more than one coming?

Comment: @MichaelAzarenko Yes, even if more than one is coming.